# How to connect RasaCore Chatbot to Messenger?

Tags: python, chatbot, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-chatbot, rasa-core

I am trying to connect RasaCore Chatbot to Facebook Messenger.

How can I do it via run script if I do not have the URL (the callback URL to setup webhook)?

I cannot do it either using python and I don't know why.

Is this the only instruction? I cannot find any other:
https://core.rasa.com/connectors.html#using-run-script

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! I have it!

1. If you are using ngrok, you need to add '/webhook' to the address that ngrok created.
2. If you are using first tutorial from Rasa ( https://core.rasa.com/tutorial_basics.html ), there are mistakes in directories (not models/dialogue but models/current*/dialogue , *its default name used in this tutorial, but this is the name of your folder and models/nlu/current should be models/current/nlu ) you have to check it.
3. The 'App Secret Code' from FB you can find in Basic Settings (Tab: Settings) of your App.
4. Code in the tutorial is much better than 'bigger' code cloned from respiratory suggested on the beginning of this tutorial :)

Answer (score 0):

you can set up a local url on your machine using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) - then you also have a URL where facebook can send messages.

[here](https://core.rasa.com/connectors.html#facebook-messenger-setup) are the instructions for connecting to facebook

Comment: thank you! But I am not sure how to connect it with my bot. Could you be a little more specific?

Comment: I can connect a bot if its built as a simple python code, but I have no idea how to do it when its Rasa

Comment: amn41 thank you, but this is the link I have put in my question :D It does not working in my case and I am stucked.